# having trouble finding the covariance(X,Y) of a PDF

Tags: statistics

I am trying to compute the co-variance where $f(x,y)$ = $e^{-y}$ for $x,y > 0, E(X) = 1$ and $E(Y) = 2$

I understand that $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$ but I am having trouble computing $E(XY)$.

My attempt starts with $E(XY)$ = $$\iint_0^∞  xyf(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$

but my answer ends up being infinity, which I know is wrong, could it possibly be an issue with my bounds?

Comment: Your integral should be of $xyf(x,y)\,dx\,dy,$ not of $xyf(X,Y)\,dx\,dy. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the $f(x,y)$ you gave is not a valid pdf.   It looks like you have the wrong support.

$f(x,y)=e^{-y} ~\big[0\leq x\leq y\big]$ will give $\mathsf E(X)=1$ and $\mathsf E(Y)=2$.

So I suggest you should be looking for: $$\mathsf E(XY)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^y x y~e^{-y}~\mathsf d x~\mathsf d y$$

Comment: The original function that was given in the question was a conditional PDF $f(x|y)$ = $e^{-(y-x)}$ for y > x and 0 for y < x. Does this help verify that it will be in the bounds you just gave? (it was also given that $f(x) = e^{-x}$ )

Comment: @JozefMilenkiewicz  That would be $f_X(x)= e^{-x}~\big[0\leqslant x\big]$ and $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)= e^{-(y-x)}~\big[0\leqslant x\leqslant y\big]$, producing $f_{X,Y}(x,y)= e^{-y}~\big[0\leqslant x \leqslant y\big]$

Comment: would this make the support 0 -> inf  for dx and x -> inf for dy ?

Comment: If you mean is $\mathsf E(XY)=\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty xy~e^{-y}~\mathsf dy~\mathsf d x$, then yes, that is also valid. @JozefMilenkiewicz